# Duda con método burbuja en java

Tags: java, ordenamiento

tengo un codigo el cual utiliza el algoritmo del ordenamiento burbuja (bubble sort) el cual es el siguiente:

public class Burbuja {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    int arreglo[] = new int[5];
    int auxiliar = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


    //introducir valores desde teclado

    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("introduce el valor de la posición " + i + " :");
        arreglo[i] = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");
    }

    //Aplicando el metodo de la burbuja

    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < arreglo.length; j++) {
            if (arreglo[i] > arreglo[j]) {
                auxiliar = arreglo[i];
                arreglo[i] = arreglo[j];
                arreglo[j] = auxiliar;
            }
        }
    }

    //Mostrando los datos ordenados
    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arreglo[i] + " ");
    }

}
```

}
El programa funciona de forma correcta, sin embargo me genera una duda en el ciclo for especificamente en la siguiente instrucción:
**for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length - 1; i++)**

Mi duda es, por que se pone el -1 , ya que por lo que yo entiendo ese bucle es el que se encarga de dar las vueltas y ejecutar la condicion de ordenamiento, pero no comprendo el porque se pone -1 si creo yo tendria que dar todas las vueltas para asegurarse que los elementos estan correctamente ordenados, sin embargo si yo le quito el -1 sale el error de desbordamiento, si pudieran ayudarme a aclarar la duda por favor, muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: El porque de ese "-1" es muy sencillo de entender, el "alma de este método es la comparación **arreglo[ i ] > arreglo[ j ]**, y no tiene ningún sentido comparar la última posición, con la... última posición, igual está no es la forma óptima de algoritmo, en ella se usa un while con un for interno, el while en modo "loop eterno" y las comparación es **arreglo[ i ] > arreglo[ i + 1 ]** donde queda más claro el porque.

Answer (score 1):

**Es para evitar comparar la última celda con la última celda**

Aunque no evita comparar la primera con la primera (xD)

Pon esta línea `System.out.println("comparando array[" + i + "] con array[" + j + "]");` para ir viendo lo que hace y te darás cuenta. Asi:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
     for (int j = i + 1; j < arreglo.length; j++) {
         System.out.println("comparando array[" + i + "] con array[" + j + "]");
         if (arreglo[i] > arreglo[j]) {
             auxiliar = arreglo[i];
             arreglo[i] = arreglo[j];
             arreglo[j] = auxiliar;
         }
     }
 }
```

Irás viendo que celdas compara asi:

```
comparando array[0] con array[1]
comparando array[0] con array[2]
comparando array[0] con array[3]
// ...etc
```

Te he puesto, además, el `int j = i + 1` para que no compare la primera con la primera. Si sacas el `+1` y lo dejas como lo tenías, veras que inicialmente compara:

```
comparando array[0] con array[0]
// Cosa innecesaria
```

---

**Por que `array.length -1` es el último valor del array ?**

Se pone el -1 por que el tamaño del arreglo es siempre 1 punto mas grande que el valor de la última celda.

Esto es por que la primera celda, realmente es la celda [0]

Es decir:

```
arreglo = ["a", "b", "c"]
arreglo.length // Esto es 3. Por que arreglo tiene 3 cosas dentro. Es de tamaño 3.
arreglo[0] // Esto es "a"
arreglo[1] // Esto es "b"
arreglo[2] // Esto es "c"
arreglo[3] // Esto es ERROR, por que no existe esta celda.
```

Entonces, como que arreglo.lenght tiene el valor de 3, por que tiene 3 "cosas" dentro:

```
x = arreglo.length 
arreglo[x]   // ERROR
arreglo[x-1] // Esto es "c"
```

Simplemente tienes que interiorizar que en programación cuando cuentas cosas las cuentas normales (un-dos-tres), pero cuando accedes a ellas sempre se empieza por el zero (zero-un-dos).

Comment: Hola ferter3006, cuando estamos iterando, siempre usamos **i < array.length;** por lo que tu respuesta...

Comment: exacto, mientras 1 sea MAS PEQUEÑA de array.length (es decir hasta arrray.lenght -1)

Comment: El OP pregunta porque tiene que poner como condicional **i < array.length -1;** y es la respuesta que no das, se entiende?.

Comment: Ok, lo pillo, ahora sí ha quedado claro ¿verdad?. Gracias por la aclaración Marce. El caffé aún no me havia echo efecto xD. Un saludo

Comment: Maestro, no puede estar mejor!!!